# angular2-jwt: AuthHttp causes an error 'Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.'

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt, authhttp

when I use AuthHttp from angular2-jwt in code below, I see error:

"Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1."

```
public getData(): Observable<User[]>{
const url = environment.apiUrl + "users";

return this.authHttp
  .get<User[]>(url)
  .map((res: User[]) => res);
  }
```

If I use http: HttpClient, code works well.

What to change in this code to run it with AuthHttp?

Comment: Could you include some more code? For instance where you assign this.authHttp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
   public getData(): Observable<User[]>{
    const url = environment.apiUrl + `users`;

    return this.authHttp
      .get(url)
      .map((res: Response) => <User[]>res.json());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using it correctly ?

I'd expect it to look like this:

```
this.http.get(url) 
      .map( (res) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.thing = data,
        err => console.log(error),
        () => console.log('Request Complete')
      );
```

Comment: Yes it is correct, subscribe is in component file. When I used http: HttpClient it worked, but  AuthHttp not.  I think problem is with using type User[] but id like to map response into User[] in service.